# Switch direction of [aws-cloudformation] and [amazon-cloudformation] synonym

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Currently, there are 6,293 questions with the [amazon-cloudformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-cloudformation) tag.  The [aws-cloudformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-cloudformation) tag is a synonym for [amazon-cloudformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-cloudformation).  However, as can be seen [here](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/), the official branding for CloudFormation is "**AWS CloudFormation**", not "**Amazon CloudFormation**".

Answer (score 3):

what you've said makes sense to me and I know there are other tags which could benefit from a similar exercise.

It would be great to hear from the community to see whether this is how they'd like AWS tags to be mapped going forward.

Answer (score 1):

The direction of this tag synonym relationship has now been swapped as you suggested, following [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421940/1478931); [aws-cloudformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-cloudformation) is now the primary tag, with [amazon-cloudformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-cloudformation) as a synonym of it.