# Amazon Collective launch and tag discussion

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request, collectives

As [announced on The Overflow Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/12/07/aws-joins-collectives-on-stack-overflow/), the AWS Collective is the newest Collective on Stack Overflow. The team at AWS is looking forward to engaging with and supporting developers on the Collective.

The team at AWS has done an assessment of the Amazon-related tags on Stack Overflow as part of defining what [tags are included in the Collective](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/aws?tab=tags). They have proposed to consolidate/synonymize a number of tags. There are two lists below, and we are requesting feedback on these proposed changes. There is also noted agreement on an open synonym request.

Community Managers will execute these changes, so there will be no work needed from the community.

**To those who are active in these tags: Do you have any concerns? Are there any reasons these changes should not be made?** Discussion will be open until further notice, and we’ll make the updates after it concludes. The proposed updates are below.

### Proposed synonym mappings for consolidation:

#### Where all tags are already Amazon-associated

| Target | Synonym(s) |
| --- | --- |
| [amazon-elasticache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-elasticache) | [aws-elasticache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-elasticache) |
| [amazon-elb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-elb) | [aws-load-balancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-load-balancer) |
| [amazon-fsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-fsx) | [aws-fsx-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-fsx-windows) |
| [amazon-kinesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-kinesis) | [aws-kinesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-kinesis) |
| [amazon-kinesis-analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-kinesis-analytics) | [amazon-kinesis-analytics-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-kinesis-analytics-sql) |
| [amazon-kms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-kms) | [aws-kms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-kms) |
| [amazon-neptune](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-neptune) | [aws-neptune](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-neptune) |
| [aws-acm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-acm) | [amazon-acm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-acm) |
| [aws-dms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-dms) | [amazon-dms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-dms) |
| [aws-glue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-glue) | [amazon-glue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-glue) |
| [aws-ssm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-ssm) | [aws-systems-manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-systems-manager) [amazon-ssm-agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ssm-agent) |
| [aws-step-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-step-functions) | [aws-state-machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-state-machine) |
| [amazon-transcribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-transcribe)<sup>*</sup> | [aws-transcribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-transcribe) |

<sub>*Though [amazon-transcribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-transcribe) has fewer questions, the proposal is to make that tag the primary</sub>

#### Where the proposed tag to be synonymized is not explicitly Amazon-associated

The Amazon team did their due diligence and feels confident that all questions that use these tags are related to AWS technology.

| Target | Synonym |
| --- | --- |
| [amazon-athena](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-athena) | [athena](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/athena) |
| [amazon-kinesis-firehose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-kinesis-firehose) | [firehose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firehose) |
| [aws-amplify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-amplify) | [amplify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amplify) |
| [aws-iot-greengrass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-iot-greengrass) | [greengrass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greengrass) |

### Proposed swap of synonym and target:

| Current target | Proposed target (current synonym) | Note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [amazon-cloudformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-cloudformation) | [aws-cloudformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-cloudformation) | Per [this open request from 2021](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409326/switch-direction-of-aws-cloudformation-and-amazon-cloudformation-synonym) |

We may add additional proposals in the coming week, after additional investigation from Amazon and review of any responses here.

Answer (score 92):

Standardize on `aws-*` tags as the target.  If synonymizing these tags is a part of this collective effort, then it's best to just use `aws-*`.  The reason for this is simple - AWS is a household name at this point.

Comment: I agree. "Amazon" is off-topic for Stack Overflow, but their AWS offerings can be on-topic.

Comment: Agree that AWS is the better choice, but either all AWS or all Amazon would be better than a half and half mix.

Comment: It should be AWS.  There are some Amazon tags that are on topic that are distinct from AWS, like [tag:amazon-product-api]

Comment: +1, [this is how it was mostly done in the past](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bstatus-completed%5D+amazon) already. There may be some exceptions though, like [for \[amazon-cognito\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366061/1048572) where "Amazon" (not "AWS") is part of the official brand name.

Comment: The intention of the proposed synonym mappings for tags is to match the official service name rather than to prefix all AWS related tags with amazon. Today there are combinations of tags starting with aws and amazon. With the proposed change the number of tags for the collective would be lower than without and include more AWS related answers from the community than today.

Comment: @ChrisWilliams:  The convention for synonyms is to combine what users are *actually* asking about under a common name.  I've only ever seen or heard AWS-oriented services talked about as "aws-*", and while I recognize that there is an official name to it, synonyms don't replace documentation or customer outreach; they're just a convenient way to make it so that someone's question gets to the right eyeballs.

Answer (score 71):

While there's a case to be made for calling everything `aws-*`, that doesn't really seem like the most correct solution, universally, because that isn't always how the services are actually named or how they're referenced in the official documentation.

The individual services within Amazon Web Services all have canonical names, not all of which begin with or include "AWS."

Granted, services like [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/), [AWS IAM](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/), [AWS Certificate Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/), and [AWS Fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/) are all officially marketed as "AWS ${thing}," but there are a number of prominent, contrary examples, such as [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/). [Amazon EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/), [Amazon CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/), and [Amazon SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) which have always been branded as "Amazon ${thing}."

So I'd suggest that there's a stronger case for configuring the tags as proposed above -- matching the target (canonical) tags to the names Amazon uses when branding the individual services, and making the alternative a synonym.

Comment: I see value in using canonical tags as the services are named.

Comment: Pretty sure aws-s3 will be just as recognizable as amazon-s3 and having one tag prefix is valuable despite AWS's confusing nomenclature (surely rooted in history as these are some of the oldest services).

Answer (score 3):

On the subject of the tags in the AWS Collective, the tags for the official AWS SDKs are currently missing from the Collective. Being a developer focused site, those should really be added to the collective. For example:

- [AWS SDK for JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sdk-js) – [aws-sdk-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sdk-js)
- [AWS SDK for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sdk-java) – [aws-sdk-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sdk-java)
- [AWS SDK for Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sdk-go) – [aws-sdk-go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sdk-go)
- [AWS SDK for Python (Boto3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boto3) – [boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boto3)
- [AWS SDK for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-php-sdk) – [aws-php-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-php-sdk)
- [AWS SDK for NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sdk-nodejs) – [aws-sdk-nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sdk-nodejs)
- [AWS SDK for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sdk-cpp) – [aws-sdk-cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sdk-cpp)
- [AWS SDK for Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sdk-ruby) – [aws-sdk-ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sdk-ruby)
- [AWS SDK for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sdk-net) – [aws-sdk-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sdk-net)
- [AWS SDK for Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sdk-rust) – [aws-sdk-rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sdk-rust)

And while we are discussing synonyms, I really think the [boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boto3) tag should have a synonym of [aws-sdk-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sdk-python) to match the tags for all the other AWS SDKs. If someone is just searching on the site for information on the AWS SDK for Python, they may not know it is called Boto3.

Comment: Thanks for drawing attention to these, Mark! AWS reviewed these tags, and other SDK tags, and we've added 15 total to the collective. `boto3` is added with its current name, for now.

Answer (score 3):

On behalf of both Stack Overflow and AWS, thank you! We deeply appreciate your input. We spent time reflecting on your thoughts, speaking with experts in AWS technologies, and reviewing your comments. Ultimately, we feel it’s important to provide uniform clarity across Stack Overflow that matches the search terms developers use on other platforms. Utilizing canonical tags that follow the formal product names reduces confusion and enables everyone to find the right answers as quickly as possible. Additionally, we will continue to ensure only relevant tags are included in the AWS Collective, regardless of prefix. Thus, we will align the tags with the specific product names.

Comment: The tag changes have been completed.