# Should there be canonicals for common typos?

Tags: discussion, typographical-error

For example, a possibly common beginner typo in Python is misspelling `lambda` as `lamda`. However questions that ask about their code that does not work because they spelled misspelled a keyword are typo questions that get closed.

However, if the typo is sufficiently common, there could possibly be a canonical question so that users searching their error message into Google can find a Q&A that boils down to *'Make sure you spell `lambda` correctly.'* But how could such a canonical Q&A asked without being considered a typo question in and of itself?

Maybe something like:

> Why does misspelling `lambda` cause such a cryptic error message?

Any ideas? Or is this not necessary as beginners should always check their keywords to be spelled correctly, no matter how common a certain misspelling is?

Another example is ["SyntaxError: invalid syntax" on valid statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19472645/16217248). That question is clearly caused by a typo, a missing closing brace. But I feel the question could be salvageable if generalized in a way that the answer boils down to just the second paragraph of the answer:

> In general, if you get a `SyntaxError` on a line and the error message makes no sense, it is usually a missing closing brace or closing parenthesis on the previous line (although it can also be you are missing a `:` at the end of an `if` or `for` statement on the previous line).

Comment: the only time such questions may actually be useful is when the given typo produces a rather unique error message that people are likely to search

Comment: Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72977186

Comment: @KevinB Or a cryptic error message that is unlikely to point to the true cause of the problem.

Comment: assuming the error message can't be caused by dozens of other things, sure.

Comment: This [MySQL question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515347/how-can-i-fix-mysql-error-1064) is an example of a question about a generic error message that can have all kinds of meanings.

Comment: @user16217248 "cryptic" is no good argument. SO needs questions that are searchable and when an issue can cause many different error messages, then the correct question can hardly be found. So allowing questions types which can't be research well and require others to point to the matching dupe, doesn't work well.

Comment: "_Why does misspelling lambda cause such a cryptic error message?_" seems like rocky ground to me. There are two types of "why"s. One is about mechanics, which you can explain by explaining source code and how it runs. That's fine, but I don't find it to be very interesting unless it's actually tricky to figure out. The other type is about design decisions and potentially design philosophy, and you can only answer that if the people who wrote the design spoke their minds about that specific decision publicly. Also, design philosophy for error messages is a pretty broad topic in itself I think.

Comment: Maybe more generic/canonical, some Q&A about "How to troubleshoot/debug 'Syntax Error' issues?", with a few common examples, and the technique(s) to solve them...

Comment: There's been a lot of work on improving CPython's SyntaxError messages lately.  Before writing a canonical, consider opening an issue asking for this specific case to be diagnosed with a "did you mean 'lambda'?" message.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I did, but it doesn't look like it's likely to be addressed https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/112384

Comment: Indeed, @starball, "why?" questions are usually unconstructive. In most cases, a user asking "why isn't '§' allowed in identifiers" isn't interested in either a technically accurate or historically accurate answer, they just want to express their frustration.

Comment: If it were my site, the answer would be "yes" to the title. Mostly because I think it reduces friction to give people some freedom to do things from the perspective of providing some kind of minimal schooling, even if it does not align with the goals of the site. It isn't my site though. The actual owners of the site have put a very clear and directly enforceable rule in place in the form of the "typo" close reason. As long as that rule exists and has no "but if it happens a lot it is okay" clause, we have no business creating canonicals that circumvent it.

Comment: [AWS Lambda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWS_Lambda) (capital "L") adds to the confusion. Related: *[Amazon Collective launch and tag discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421940)*

Answer (score 27):

### A frame challenge

Does misspelling `lambda` actually result in a *cryptic* error message?

```
$ python3.11
Python 3.11.2 (main, Apr  5 2023, 03:08:14) [GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> lamda spam, eggs, bacon, beans: "sorry, baked beans are off"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    lamda spam, eggs, bacon, beans: "sorry, baked beans are off"
          ^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It's not *great*, in that the error isn't detected until the first parameter. The reason, of course, is that the parser interprets `lamda` as an identifier name, and there isn't a grammar rule that would allow two identifiers in a row without anything in between.

But **this is exactly what happens when misspelling any other keyword**. There are at least two things that could be addressed here:

- Why does the issue get detected the way that it does?
- What is "syntax", and therefore what does `SyntaxError` mean?

But clearly, **neither of those is specific to `lambda`**.

### "Typos" vs typos

A literal mistake in spelling seems, to me, like it doesn't belong in the same category as more severe errors that an experienced programmer could commit by inattention. The latter are still easily thought of as "typos", **but for a beginner they could plausibly represent a *conceptual* problem**.

**Misspelling `lambda` isn't like that. It doesn't point at a lack of conceptual understanding**, but only at a pure lack of knowledge (the fact that the English language has loaned the name of a Greek letter and treats it as a word, and that programmers sometimes use this word to describe anonymous functions). That knowledge doesn't *inform* the act of programming; if the keyword were e.g. instead `parrot`, then that would equally well become something that programmers would have to "just know", and which is *completely orthogonal to* the underlying concepts (functions as first-class objects; using higher-order functions or callback functions; etc.).

On the other hand, while an experienced programmer who isn't paying attention might mess up the indentation of Python code, a neophyte **actually requires an explanation** for why indentation in Python is important, what rules Python will use to interpret that indentation, and the logical principles necessary to inspect and verify that indentation. Further, in this particular case it's *difficult to exhibit* the problem accurately, because of how code indentation (especially when tabs are involved) interacts with the Markdown parser.

**Which is exactly why we [do have such a canonical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722/)**, which was crafted many years after the first such questions started showing up. And why I've put a lot of work into re-routing old duplicate closures there, when appropriate. There are a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295938/) related [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024435/) that really do deserve to be separate, but [basically everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492387) that cites a specific indentation-related `SyntaxError` should get hammered - [even if](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423085/after-6-years-a-question-was-closed-as-a-duplicate-in-favor-of-a-lower-scored-q/423086#423086) they're popular - because they're clearly not as high quality nor as helpful to those who actually encounter the problem.

Oh, and there are [absolutely tons of outstanding duplicates there](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+IndentationError+closed%3A0), by the way. Please help. That query, surely, greatly understates the problem.

### Typos vs idiosyncratic logical errors

There are a lot of questions I close because OP has clearly **demonstrated all the necessary understanding** required to solve the problem and has simply not thought it through, or else is getting stuck on a misconception or something that **can't readily be put into words** that could allow people with the same issue to **find an appropriate question with a search engine**.

I try hard to look for patterns in how beginners mess things up (one common example is writing a loop to add elements to a container, but re-creating the container inside the loop; so I [showed that as a non-working approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75666408) when I wrote a general how-to about sequentially adding elements to a container based on an input source).

But sometimes there just isn't a reasonable way to sum that up (never mind the title OP chose for the question). These questions need to be closed because they fundamentally can only be answered in "help desk" mode and can't possibly help build a reference library. I use the typo close reason because, indeed, **"the problem was resolved in a manner that is unlikely to help others"**.

Another common case is that OP has written code that, effectively, attempts to do the same thing in two different parts of the code; and one of them works and the other doesn't; and the question is asking how to fix the non-working way; and OP doesn't seem to realize that the answer is *already in the code*. While it's sometimes *possible* to edit this down to a coherent minimal reproducible example, typically it seems like this is doing the OP a disservice. Editing the question down to only the wrong approach, in turn, sometimes results in something where that "wrong approach" is not at all helpful, and it would be better to get rid of that completely and rephrase the question as a how-to question. Except *that* question is probably a duplicate, and it's *also one that OP has already solved*.

Comment: For context, the (now deleted) question that prompted this discussion was a misspeling of `lambda` inside a `map` expression, which emits `SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?`

Comment: Those canonicals always rub me the wrong way when the author doesn't make them CW. :( If you need help with closing some of those, there is always [this room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253110/cv-pls-old-questions) which doesn't have the 6 month activity limitation of SOCVR. All other rules are the same.

Comment: @snakecharmerb there aren't "map expressions"; `map` is just a *function*. But yeah, I see why it would do that; it's guessing that the missing comma is between `lamda` as an argument and the other arguments (that were actually supposed to be parameters for the lambda).

Comment: @snakecharmerb Except it didn't, it said something like that and then on the line under, `^^^^`  arrows pointing and screaming BUG HERE. After which one has to look at the line indicated, possibly for several seconds, before finding the bug. Someone who can't resolve a bug when the compiler points an arrow at it probably doesn't have what it takes to become a programmer. Trouble-shooting is the hardest part of the trade and one is expected to deal with _far_ more intricate bugs without being so lucky as having the compiler holding hands with the programmer every time.

Comment: @Lundin come, now. I've definitely seen people develop basic analytical skills once it's sufficiently impressed upon them that they won't be able to get away with not doing so. Only very recently did Python error messages start underlining entire tokens instead of placing a single `^` (and historically it has been at either the start or end of the token text). Aside from which, this only indicates where the error was *detected*, not the ultimate cause. For example, `print foo` in 3.x will highlight the `foo`, and the error message hasn't always suggested missing parentheses, either.

Comment: But even then, closing the nth question asking the same seemingly obvious thing *as a duplicate* is surely much better than trying to get them all closed for other reasons and eventually deleted. The canonical can be an actual teachable moment.

Answer (score 10):

I think "Why does misspelling lambda cause such a cryptic error message?" is probably a worthwhile question to have. However, a different one than what somebody who has a syntax error really needs.

A proper canonical should probably go over what syntax errors are in much broader terms. And attempt to explain common causes as well as common ways to address them. Something akin to this :

> Syntax errors are when the code does not make sense because of an issue.
>
> Common problems are:
>
> - mismatched brackets
> - missing delimiters (commas, semicolons)
> - keywords in the wrong context
> - misspelled keywords
>
> Common ways to address:
>
> - check the line that you get an error for. Very likely something at it or around it is misspelled or otherwise wrong.
> - use syntax highlighting to find incorrect keywords
> - use <common tools for detecting problems such as linters or enabling compiler warnings or others depending on the language>
> - <potentially explain how to read the error to narrow down the cause, if applicable>

This way it would be applicable to many more users that have this problem. Not an exceptionally small subset of them that managed to 1. misspell a keyword 2. that keyword was `lambda`.

---

By comparison "Why does misspelling lambda cause such a cryptic error message?" is interesting from a different perspective - how is the parsing done in order to cause this error. It is rather niche and not particularly wide enough problem but one that is still relevant. I just do not think it is what somebody who experienced a syntax error and is searching for a solution looks for immediately. It is more of an academic curiosity which is still valid.

Comment: There is a very broad (some would say terrible) [PHP question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/1255289) that might serve as an example (some would say a warning) of what such a canonical would end up looking like.

Comment: Zoinks! @miken32 that's a canonical that I would only use if I could point an asker directly at the section that applied to them. Without help the asker probably wouldn't recognize the answer even if they did find it.

Comment: @user4581301 yeah when I do use it, I try to remember to leave a comment with the specific link. I don't use it much anymore because I'm not entirely happy with it in concept, but it can be a quick way to deal with low quality questions.

Answer (score -2):

No, no, and no again. We don't need more canonicals, and we **especially** don't need more open-ended canonicals. This is because canonicals were a mistake.

Stack Overflow is intended to provide specific, focused answers to specific, focused problems. Canonicals are the antithesis of this because they attempt to address commonly-encountered issues, but those issues are commonly encountered because there are so many different scenarios in which they can arise. Therefore any canonical invariably ends up containing wall-of-text answers attempting to cover as many of those causes as possible - and inevitably these answers fail to do so.

The wall-of-text issue is also why canonicals are not useful to askers. They have a simple problem caused by their lack of fundamental understanding of a programming language, and now you've pointed them to what's effectively a thesis on every possible cause for their problem - that's only going to confuse them more, not address their specific issue. More useful to them to close that question with a more specific close reason, IMO.

Finally, and most importantly, Stack Overflow doesn't exist to be all things to all people. It does not exist to cover ever single possible programming issue under the sun, nor to hold your hand. If you aren't capable of using an IDE, or a search engine, or your brain, or a combination of all three, to figure out a trivial problem like a syntax error... then maybe programming isn't for you. Just because there's a bar to entry, doesn't always mean it's discriminatory that you can't meet it.

*edit:* There is nothing inherently wrong with a wall of text - I have, for example, just written one in this answer, and I will always take a more thorough and detailed explanation over a concise one. But - and here's the rub - *the kind of people who most need to be reading walls of text are the ones least interested in doing so*. The tl;dr gang doesn't seek to understand, just to get their question answered; the binary "answer" or "close" are more useful to them than teaching them to fish.

Comment: Does for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72482298 come across to you as a "wall of text"?

Comment: Yes. Don't take that the wrong way, it's a helpful Q&A and it does a good job explaining - but the users who need to read it most, are the ones who aren't going to bother.

Comment: So you would prefer to require three close votes instead of one, and also deliberately ignore the opportunity to show relevant information to people who could benefit from it? And you imagine that people cannot be cured of their habits?

Comment: I don't mind canonicals, but we can't respectably manage them so they inevitable end up breaking due to too much lording over it. Take the classic [NPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). I'm sure at some point that was a useful, readable canonical that wouldn't short circuit the brain of the people with the knowledge level which need a canonical like this. But over time it has grown into a monster and even has a list of things in it. As soon as content has a list of things in it on Stack Overflow, that is a sign we went too far IMO.

Comment: @Gimby That's exactly correct.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The people who could benefit from it **are not going to**, because they're going to see a wall of text, their eyes are going to glaze over, and they are going to close the tab. If you aren't able to debug simple issues like those of syntax, you sure as hell aren't capable of gleaning how to fix your issue from a wall of text that enumerates every possible way you could have got things wrong.